# Erro ao analisar XML, linha 3147, coluna 2: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: html, blogger

Estou fazendo algumas mudanças em um blog e aparece esse erro quando eu tento salvar.
A linha onde ele fala que está o erro é a segunda.

```
<!--Copyright-->
<div id='copyrights'> 
<div class='margin-1200'>
  <p>Coprights @ 2016, <a href='http://www.templateism.com' id='mycontent'>Blogger Template</a> Designed By Templateism | <a href='https://templatelib.com'>Templatelib</a></p>
  </div>  
</div>


<script>(function(d,e,s){if(d.getElementById(&quot;likebtn_wjs&quot;))return;a=d.createElement(e);m=d.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];a.async=1;a.id=&quot;likebtn_wjs&quot;;a.src=s;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)})(document,&quot;script&quot;,&quot;//w.likebtn.com/js/w/widget.js&quot;);</script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

O que eu tenho que fazer pro erro sumir?
obs: eu não sei NADA de html, então quem puder me ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: Tem certeza que `<div id='copyrights'>` é a linha 3147?

Comment: Não foi possível reproduzir o erro com o código postado. Queira [edit] sua pergunta com todas as partes relevantes. Aqui tem umas leituras importantes para ver como adequar melhor sua postagem e aumentar a chance de obter ajuda: [Tour], [Ask], [Help] e principalmente, como criar um [Mcve].

Answer (score 0):

@Maria Santos, apenas com esse trecho fica difícil dar uma resposta exata, no entanto ele oferece alguns elementos que podem ser útil.

1º passo descomente esse trecho do Javascript:

Troque : `//w.likebtn.com/js/w/widget.js&quot;);</script>`

Por : `w.likebtn.com/js/w/widget.js&quot;);</script>`

Remova essa duas barras "//".

Faz isso e comenta o resultado abaixo da resposta que vamos ajustando.